# Save different values on Async Storage React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm making an app in which I'm trying to save data in the local storage of the phone. I'm using async storage for that but when I try to save a different value with a different key it just updates. Need help, please. Below is my read and write code.

```
 const storeData = async () => {
try {
  let id = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);
var id33 = id;
  const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(region);
  await AsyncStorage.setItem(id33, "Andres");
} catch (e) {
  // saving error
}
```

};

```
const fetchAllItems = async () => {
try {
  const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
  const items = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
  alert(items);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

};

Thank you and sorry for bothering you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Before I start console.log(e) your errors in try catch blocks when coding. Will save you time**

I made a copy of your code based on the info you gave me, and everything works . Full example here (https://snack.expo.dev/dYwSij6kV) Click `Editor` on the very bottom then turn on `panel` and then click on `logs` to see the output.

I got the output so it is showing multiple keys.

```
►1:["tbl6ai","Andres"]
►2:["vd73b","Andres"]
►3:["uemcr","Andres"]
►4:["n5kie","Andres"]
►5:["EXPO_CONSTANTS_INSTALLATION_ID","3c2eee1f-f917-40ce-a9e6-ce73f83183b6"]
►6:["8a1cd","Andres"]
►7:["1d40y","Andres"]
```

I recommned going through every line of your code where you use async storage to see if your missing something. If that still doesn't fix it delete your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm install`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help I will try that!